# Simple Socket Server in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, sockets, tcp

Is there a way to quickly bind to a TCP port/ip address and simply print out all information to STDOUT? I have a simple debugging solution which writes things to 127.0.0.1:4444 and I'd like to be able to simply bind up a port from bash and print everything that comes across. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: related http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49936/dev-tcp-listen-instead-of-nc-listen

Answer (score 135, accepted):

```
$ nc -k -l 4444 > filename.out
```

see [`nc(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nc)

Comment: Any way to do it that doesn't require it to run in a loop, ie bind until killed? I'm repeatedly connecting and disconnecting to the socket and `nc` dies if I don't run it like this: `while true; do nc -l 4444; done`.

Comment: On some distros you'll need to change it to  'nc -k -l -p 4444'.

Comment: If you use ncat instead of nc, you can have multiple concurrent connections while using the exact same syntax.

Comment: yes, use `ncat` instead of `nc` (it comes bundled with `nmap` and it's a modern day incarnation of `nc`)

Answer (score 61):

Just because you asked how to do it in `bash`, though `netcat` answer is very valid:

```
  $ exec 3<>/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/4444
  $ cat <&3
```

Comment: But that doesn't work for listening. I don't think its possible to listen using strictly bash

Comment: This solution indeed requires a listening server. Bash cannot do this by means of `/dev/tcp` as explained in http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/49947/13746

Comment: Listening? That’s what xinetd is for! :D

Comment: @Evi1M4chine wow, that's a blast from the past...

Answer (score 18):

That is working as you expecting:

```
 nc -k -l 4444 |bash
```

and then you

```
echo "ls" >/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/4444
```

then you see the listing performed by bash.

*[A Brief Security Warning]*
Of course if you leave a thing like this running on your computer, you have a wide open gateway for all kinds of attacks because commands can be sent from any user account on any host in your network.  This implements no security (authentication, identification) whatsoever and sends all transmitted commands unencrypted over the network, so it can very easily be abused.

Comment: If you don't have `/dev/tcp`, you can run: `echo "ls" | nc 127.0.0.1 4444`

Comment: @fzbd: there is no /dev/tcp. this is special bash file, so ``ls`` will not show this

Comment: @MarcinFabrykowski Correct, but if you run these commands on other shells, there is no handler available. It can also fail if your bash isn't compiled with `--enable-net-redirections`.

Answer (score 9):

Adding an answer using `ncat` that @Freedom_Ben alluded to:

```
ncat -k -l 127.0.0.1 4444
```

and explanation of options from man ncat:

```
-k, --keep-open            Accept multiple connections in listen mode
-l, --listen               Bind and listen for incoming connections
```

Comment: `ncat` comes with `nmap` and supports concurrent connections, while the legacy `nc` command does not.