# what are my options for a generic server?

Tags: linux, server-side

I want to create a generic server (on a Linux machine) such that when someone connects to the server's port, they can enter one line, which is then passed as an argument to the server, which processes it by executing a command with the line being the parameters, and then returns its output.

I am pretty sure there is a "generic" way of defining such a server using linux commands -- any ideas what those might be?

Comment: I think it is called `ssh` ....

Comment: I don't want the server to require a login, just connecting to a port and getting the information from there.

Comment: `ssh` can be configured (using public keys...) to avoid any *explicit* login. Read a good [ssh tutorial](http://support.suso.com/supki/SSH_Tutorial_for_Linux). But you still have secure encrypted exchanges.

Comment: `ssh` without security is `rsh`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple Socket Server in Bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739196/simple-socket-server-in-bash)