# How to find an unknown IP with a given port

Tags: c#, networking, dynamic, ipv4

I'm using a Raspberry Pi as a server in our network with IP: 172.20.X.X/16

The plan is to send a broadcast-message to the port `15555`. The Server will receive the message and send me his **eth0-IP**.

As I'm not the best in networking, I have problems to make a script that sends the IP to the broadcaster, and especially let this script get executed when the Server receives anything on port `15555`

I've read some things about the command "nc" but I don't really get if that solves my problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4739260/11397900

So at the moment I have 2 scripts:

Script 1 contains

```
#!/bin/bash

while :
do
    nc -k -l 15555 > sendIP.sh
    sleep 1
done
```

Script 2 is called sendIP and  contains atm

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Success"
```

Last but not least, my C#-Code to send a broadcast is this one:

```
private static string getServerIP(int port)
    {
        string IPString = String.Empty;

        IPEndPoint iPEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("172.20.255.255"), port);
        byte[] messageInbytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hallo");

        UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient();

        udpClient.Send(messageInbytes, messageInbytes.Length, iPEndPoint);
        udpClient.Client.ReceiveTimeout = 1000;
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                var recvBuffer = udpClient.Receive(ref iPEndPoint);
                break;
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }

        return iPEndPoint.Address.ToString();
    }
```

The expectation is, that on the Raspberry, there will stand "Success" in the console, and the c#- program finishes, but in reality, the Program won't get a response

Comment: this seems like a very unique solution to a problem you did not describe. I guearantee you if you tell us what you want to achive on a bigger scale we can help you out

Comment: also to debug your issue install wireshark on all your devices and see if the packages actually arrive otherwise you gonna have a hard time debugging and bugfixing

Comment: why not just open a connection on that port to all possible IP addresses in the subnet (except your own, duh) in parallel? Set timeout to something like 200 ms and you are set.

Comment: That is a misuse of broadcast. We have multicast for that. Broadcast interrupts every host on the LAN, but multicast only interrupts the hosts listening to the particular multicast group. In fact, IPv6 has eliminated broadcast, so you would not be able to use IPv6 with this solution, and many businesses will not approve an application that uses broadcast in such a way.

Comment: @DenisSchaf Generally I want to find out the unknown IP in my network. Let's say the Raspberry has the IP "172.20.31.54", then I want to "shout" into the network "Every host who listens on Port 15555: Give me your IP". Then the Raspberry gets the message and sends back "172.20.31.54". But I'm not very familliar with networking, so I don't know how to send a message to this Port or make the Pi listening on this Port

Comment: As soon as the pi gets active in the network you should have  him in your arp table. Try reading about arp/rarp as your mac is fixed you will be able to find the pi using this protocol without implementing you own wonky solution